# Pan Svg While dragging elements

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll, viewbox, panning

I want to achieve 'Panning' in svg while 'dragging' an element in particular direction.

Let say i select an element and start 'dragging' it upward untill it reached top of screen, now my svg should pan upwards automatically, without causing any problem with dragging.  how i can achieve this.?

i have made a small mockup of this, where user can select and drag elements. it also contain two button, which cause svg to pan upward and downward. I am achiveing 'Panning' by changing 'ViewBox' of svg. ( i have to use this logic, i cannot use any other solution);

here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/9J25r/

**Complete Code:-**

```
addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);
            var mx, my;
            var dx, dy;
            var mainsvg = document.getElementById('svg');
            var selectedElement;
            var eleTx, eleTy;

            function getSvgCordinates(event) {

                var m = mainsvg.getScreenCTM();
                var p = mainsvg.createSVGPoint();

                var x, y;

                x = event.pageX;
                y = event.pageY;

                p.x = x;
                p.y = y;
                p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

                x = p.x;
                y = p.y;

                x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
                y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

                return {x: x, y: y};
            }

            function mousedown(event) {
                if (event.target.id === 'arrow_t') {
                    panning('up');
                }
                else if (event.target.id === 'arrow_b') {
                    panning('down');
                }
                else  if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] === 'rect') {

                    selectedElement = event.target;
                    var translatexy = selectedElement.getAttribute('transform');
                    translatexy = translatexy.split('(');
                    translatexy = translatexy[1].split(',');

                    eleTx = translatexy[0];
                    translatexy = translatexy[1].split(')');
                    eleTy = translatexy[0];

                    eleTx = parseFloat(eleTx);
                    eleTy = parseFloat(eleTy);

                    var xy = getSvgCordinates(event);

                    mx = xy.x;
                    my = xy.y;

                    mx = parseFloat(mx);
                    my = parseFloat(my);

                    addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
                    addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);
                }
            }

            function drag(event) {
                var xy = getSvgCordinates(event);
                dx = xy.x - mx;
                dy = xy.y - my;

                selectedElement.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + (eleTx + dx) + ',' + (eleTy + dy) + ')');
            }
            function mouseup(event) {


                removeEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
                removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);

            }

            function panning(direction) {
                var viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox');
                viewBox = viewBox.split(' ');
                var y = parseFloat(viewBox[1]);
                if (direction === 'up')
                {
                    y+=5;
                }
                else if (direction === 'down')
                {
                    y-=5;
                }

                viewBox=viewBox[0]+' '+y+' '+viewBox[2]+' '+viewBox[3];
                svg.setAttribute('viewBox',viewBox);
            }
```

[image]

[image]

here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/9J25r/

**EDIT:- (UPDATE)**

I use the solution of Ian , it works well on the sample, but when i applied it to my original application, it did not work. check the below gif. You can see the 'gap' between mouse pointer and element. how i can remove that? .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, I've just done it with the Y/vertical for the moment...

You may want to adjust it, so that if the cursor is off the screen it adjusts the viewBox automatically as well, depends how you want it to drag (otherwise you will need to keep wiggling it to kick the drag func in).

```
var viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox');
viewBoxSplit = viewBox.split(' ');

if( ely < viewBoxSplit[1] ) {
      panning('down');
} else if( ely + +event.target.getAttribute('height')> +viewBoxSplit[1] + 300 ) {
      panning('up');
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9J25r/1/)

Comment: thats great Ian, it works well, but it did not work on my actually application. i have uploaded the gif above, kindly check that.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code to play with. It will need some tweaking whatever when it comes to the edges, depending upon what you want to do with the cursor on dragging past edges.

Comment: Well i want the svg keep panning where as cursor and element remain at the top edge. Cursor should not leave the element and element should not disappear.